# Start Long-Running Process With DBContext Access Before Returning

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to handle a particular situation with dotnet core and dependency injection. I have a Web API server that's only serving as a back-end, with a separate Vue front-end. One of the API endpoints needs to trigger a long-running download process, but then return immediately without waiting for the process to complete. The difficulty that I'm running into is that the long-running process needs database access throughout the entirety of its run. I have a DownloadHelper class that I'm adding as a singleton like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<DownloadHelper>();
```

I wanted to have the constructor of the DownloadHelper look like this so that I can pass the database context through dependency injection. The DownloadHelper class looks like this:

```
public class DownloadHelper 
{
    private CoreTestContext _context;
    public DownloadHelper(CoreTestContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
    } 

    public async Task DownloadFile(Test item, string url) {
        // Download the file from url
        // Add details of downloaded file to the test object

        item.Files.Add(new TestFile {Name = "NewFile", Path = "FilePath"});
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That's called from the web API controller (called TestController, just a scoped controller since it inherits from Controller) like this. Note that _downloadHelper is set by the API controller's constructor, passed in via dependency injection:

```
public class TestController : Controller 
{
    private DownloadHelper _downloadHelper;
    public TestController(CoreTestContext context, DownloadHelper downloadHelper)
    {
        _downloadHelper = downloadHelper;
    }

    [Route("api/test/{id}/testfile"]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadTestFile(Guid id) {
        var test = _context.Tests.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)

        _downloadHelper.DownloadFile(test);

        // return without waiting for download to complete
        return Ok(book);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that the CoreTestContext is scoped, so a singleton can't receive it. How should I go about setting this up correctly? I also tried making DownloadHelper scoped, but when I did that, the _context.SaveChanges() call in DownloadFile would not work, since TestController returned and was disposed, therefor disposing DownloadHelper and its context before the actual download finished. I got an error saying _context was already disposed. What is the correct way to set up a call where the API controller can still return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a factory class to create the `CoreTestContext` and pass that to your `DownloadHelper` class instead.

```
public class CoreTestContextFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _sp;

    public CoreTestContextFactory(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _sp = sp;
    }

    public CoreTestContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return _sp.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    }
}
```

Register this as a singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<CoreTestContextFactory>();
```

Now inject this into your singleton class:

```
public class DownloadHelper 
{
    private CoreTestContextFactory _factory;

    public DownloadHelper(CoreTestContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _factory = dbContextFactory;
    } 

    public async Task DownloadFile(Test item, string url) {
        // Download the file from url
        // Add details of downloaded file to the test object

        using(var context = _factory.CreateContext())
        {
            item.Files.Add(new TestFile {Name = "NewFile", Path = "FilePath"});
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great! The one thing that I had to change was the GetRequiredService<CoreTestContext>() call. The service provider couldn't find it, for some reason - all I had to do was use _sp.CreateScope(), and then use the resulting object to call GetRequiredService<CoreTestContext>(). That ended up working! Thank you very much.